# return string as template

Tags: go, martini

I would like to return a string as a template in martini in golang :

```
m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) string {
    template := "Hello world! <form name='input' action='../first' method='post' ><input type='texte' name='toto'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"
    r.HTML(200, "post", template)

})
```

but it return me an error :
missing return at end of function

Regards & thanks
bussiere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the string so:

```
m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) string {
    return "Hello world! <form name='input' action='../first' method='post' ><input type='texte' name='toto'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"
})
```

Comment: it returns me : Hello world! <form name='input' action='../first' method='post' ><input type='texte' name='toto'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form> but no form ... just my html printed as text in my webpage

Comment: You need valid html that starts with `<html><head></head><body>.....</body></html>`

Comment: @Volker while that's true, Go handles that transparently for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use render remove the string return type from your function.

```
m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) {
    template := "Hello world! <form name='input' action='../first' method='post' ><input type='texte' name='toto'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"
    r.HTML(200, "post", template)

})
```

I am assuming "post" is a template you have already defined in your directory structure and that the string you are passing as an argument will go inside this template.

Answer (score 0):

When you render a string in martini you must use the html tags.

```
m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) string {
    template := "<html>Hello world! <form name='input' action='../first' method='post' ><input type='texte' name='toto'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></html>"
    return template

})
```

Comment: That's invalid html, please use valid html for the love of everything's holy.